# Reversing array in C with pointers

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, pointers, reverse

Trying to reverse the array. And then print it

I am trying to reverse the array by indenting from last to first element of array and copy it to another array. `arra` will be the reversed array :

Here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num, *arr, i;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    arr = (int *)malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        scanf("%d", arr + i);
    }
    
    int arra[] = {};
    /* Write the logic to reverse the array. */
    arra[0] = *(arr + num);
    for (int k = 1; k == num; k++) {
        int j = 1;
        arra[j] = *(arr + num -k);
        j++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("%d ", *(arra + i));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays in C are not dynamic, you can't do `int arra[] = {};`. Also, `*(arr + num)` is the same as `arr[num]` which is out of bounds.

Comment: There are multiple problems with this code.  In the middle loop, `int j = 1` sets `j` to `1`.  So the very next line always assigns to `arra[1]`.  The increment of `j` at the end of the loop serves no purpose and is just dead code, which most optimizers will simply delete.  Also, writing `*(arr + i)` is just an obfuscated way to write `arr[i]`.  Try to work with the language, don't fight it.

Comment: And the loop `for(int k = 1; k == num; k++)`... Unless `num == 1` then the loop will never iterate even once.

Comment: And what is the actual assignment or exercise you're trying to solve? Do you really need a new array? Or is it okay to just print the input in reverse order?

Comment: we don't need a new array there is no restrictions but I couldn't solve it by printing the input in reverse.

Comment: You have the array `arr`, with element indexes from `0` to `num - 1`. You already do a forward iteration over that array when you read the input. Now please take some time to think about how you can reverse that loop to iterate from `num - 1` to `0` (inclusive).

Comment: @Tom Karzes I am not trying to fight bro I am trying to learn, thx for comment.

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of `*(arr + num)`, write `arr[num]`  - much easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this declaration

```
int arra[] = {};
```

is invalid in C and C++.

You should define the array also allocating dynamically memory for it as for the first array or in the worst case you could define a variable length array (provided that the compiler supports VLAs) like

```
int arra[num];
```

This for loop

```
for(int k = 1; k == num; k++){
```

will iterate only one time when `num` initially is set to `1`.

Also within the body of the loop the variable `j` is created in each iteration of the loop (provided that the condition of the loop will be updated correctly) with the value `1`

```
    int j = 1;
    arra[j] = *(arr + num -k);
    j++;
```

Thus this statement

```
    arra[j] = *(arr + num -k);
```

in each iteration of the loop is equivalent to

```
    arra[1] = *(arr + num -k);
```

that does not make sense.

To copy one array into another array using pointers the for loop can look for example the following way

```
for ( int *src = arr, *dsn = arra + n; src != arr + n; ++src )
{
    *--dsn = *src;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work for multiple reasons:

- `int arra[] = {};` is an invalid definition in C,
- the loop `for(int k = 1; k == num; k++)` will exit immediately if `num` is not exactly `1`.

If you wish to reverse the array contents into a separate array, you should allocate the destination array with `malloc` and if you must use pointer, initialize them appropriately:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int num;
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1 || num <= 0)
        return 1;
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    if (!arr)
        return 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", arr + i) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    
    /* allocate the destination array */
    int *arra = (int *)malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    if (!arra)
        return 1;

    /* start copying from the end of the source array */
    int *src = arr + num;
    int *dest = arra;
    while (src > arr) {
        *dest++ = *--src;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *(arra + i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(arr);
    free(arra);
    return 0;
}
```

If the goal is to reverse the array in place using pointers, initialize a `left` and `right` pointer to both ends of the array, one pointing to the first element and one pointing to the last element, as long as the `left` pointer is smaller than the `right` pointer, swap the elements, increment the `left` pointer and decrement the `right` pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int num;
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1 || num <= 0)
        return 1;
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    if (!arr)
        return 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", arr + i) != 1)
            return 1;
    }

    for (int *left = arr, *right = arr + num - 1;
         left < right;
         left++, right--) {
        int tmp = *left;
        *left = *right;
        *right = tmp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *(arr + i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```